# Node exiting loop before handling all errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, validation, frontend

I'm doing some front-end validation on a node application with JS. I want to iterate over each field and pass back an error that the field is required with the field value. Currently, if a field is empty the error is passed back. However, if multiple fields are empty it only passes back the first error. How would I pass back every error? Code below:

```
app.post('/books/new', function (req, res, next) {
  let transaction;

  try {
    errors = [];
    let errorList = []
    for (let i in req.body) {
      if (!req.body[i]) {
        errorList.push(`${[i]} is a required field`)
        throw new Error(errorList);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }

    Library.create({
      title: req.body.title,
      author: req.body.author,
      genre: req.body.genre,
      year: req.body.year,
    })
    res.redirect('/');
  }
    // if (!req.body) { throw new Error(`${req.params[0]} required`)  } else {

    // }

  // transaction.commit();
 catch (err) {
  errors.push(err.message);
  console.log('errors', errors);
  res.render('new-book', {
    errors: errors
  })
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    throw new Error(errorList);
```

will exit the for, thus ending the method

do not throw it there, but outside the for

```
if (errorList.length > 0) {
    throw new Error(errorList);
}
```